# Method channel in flutter is not getting invoked in flutter killed state

Tags: ios, flutter, methods, channel

We need to navigate to our games screen when clicked on notification.For iOS swift we are using userNotificationCenter for notification.In our app from native iOS through method channel we are invoking method in dart side when user taps on notification.It works Properly in foreground state and background state but it does not work in killed state.

```
override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "userTapChannel", binaryMessenger:flutterViewController.binaryMessenger)
        channel.invokeMethod("pushNotificationClicked", arguments: response.notification.request.content.userInfo)

        
     
        completionHandler()
    }
```

In dart side inside main.dart

```
@override
void initState() {
const userTapChannel = MethodChannel('userTapChannel');
userTapChannel.setMethodCallHandler(pnTapCallback);

}

Future<void> pnTapCallback(MethodCall call) async {
//code removed because of security issue.For checking in killed state we did UI changes like first we turned on loader when user enters this method but it did not worked in killed state.

}
```

Please anyone can help why I am not getting call in Killed state.What should we check.
flutter sdk  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: did you get any solution? Please send this urgently if you have any workaround.

Comment: @ShivamSharma Found any solution?

Comment: @Programmer007 Yes, you need to write a callbackDispatcher